# Must the word after "can" be present tense?

Tags: tenses, modal-verbs

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD04xx/EWD498.html:

> We can found no scientific discipline, nor a hearty profession on the
>   technical mistakes of the Department of Defense and, mainly, one
>   computer manufacturer.

I'd always thought that words after "can" should be in present tense, but the above sentence doesn't sound *wrong* so now I'm wondering if this rule even exists at all.

Must the word after "can" be present tense?

Comment: This isn't the past tense of "find" - it's "to found": http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/found#Verb_2

Comment: Checking the link, I find the entire passage is badly phrased, and is almost certainly written by a non-native speaker.

Comment: The answers are correct about the specific example, but don't address the question: Can the word "can" be followed by a past-tense verb. Like "We can established no scientific discipline ..." It sounds wrong to me, but I'm not sure what the rule would be.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Love him him or hate him, know who you're talking about: this is [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra), here! His "EWDs" are worthwhile reading for anyone in computer science, even if some, like his opinions on GOTO, are notoriously inflammatory. (I agree that this sentence is confusing, but the rest is clear enough, I think, keeping in mind that it uses technical jargon of the time. Dijkstra was Dutch, so indeed, he would probably not have learned English as his first language, but note that even in this piece he seems to regard it as his "native tongue".)

Comment: @aedia: I only scanned the link briefly, but nothing suggested that the *substance* of what he said was in any way below par. But OP's particular example is only one of several where the phrasing is poor/opaque. Plus it's a curious mixture of informal/formal/academic, so I definitely wouldn't recommend it to anyone wishing to learn better English, even though it does raise some interesting points about computer science. I don't see why you think that *even in this piece he seems to regard [English] as his "native tongue"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it seemed to me from points about language - "sloppy English", "exceptionally good mastery" - that he could not help but consider himself among the proficient group, and he often nitpicked language in his work. However, I admit you piqued my curiosity, and I found [another piece, EWD514, same year](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD05xx/EWD514.html) where he says he does not in fact consider it so: "...I write these comments not in my native tongue and...combining in English clarity with the subtle use of understatement is not my greatest strength."

Comment: @aedia: By any normal standards his English is pretty good for a non-native speaker, and I certainly meant no disrespect to the man himself. I'd never heard of him before, but noting your other link, and reading more of his pronouncements, I actually have great respect him now. Just not as an exemplar of good English usage.

Comment: Dijkstra is dead, peace out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As already properly commented by aedia, the word contained in the example you presented is not the past tense of *find*, but rather a different word, *to found*, meaning *to establish.*

I'm sure you've heard it used before, in examples like:

> This company was founded in 1950.

That's the past tense. The infinitive is used in your example:

> We can found no scientific discipline.

Which can be rewritten to:

> We can establish no scientific discipline.

Comment: so are you saying the rule (infinitive after "can") *did* exist?

Comment: @Pacerier: uhm, what? why *did* exist? it still does exist...

Comment: @Pacerier I think you're still confused.  After "can" you must use the infinitive form.  In your example, the word "found" is NOT the past-tense form of "to find", but the infinitive form of a different verb, "to found".

Answer (score 7):

The word "found" is *not* present tense; it's infinitive.  "Can", in this context, is a modal verb which takes an infinitive.  The way to make sure of this is to use a verb (*be*) whose infinitive (*be*) differs from its present indicitive (*is* / *are* / etc.).

> We can *be* noisy if we want.

So, *no*, it must not be present tense, it must be infinitive.

Comment: You're exactly right, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The word "found" is the present tense. I suspect your confusion comes from thinking that it is the past tense of "find". But it is not. The word "found" is the verb form of "foundation". They could also have written "we can build no foundation for scientific discipline ... [on the mistakes of the DoD]."

Comment: Well it's not the present tense but as pointed out in the other answers it's the infinitive. It's an easy enough mistake though since most English words have the same form for the infinitive and present. [Jez, however found the perfect example in their answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44493/must-the-word-after-can-be-present-tense/44499#44499).